# Accessibility focus trap, make items inside iframe not focussable

Tags: html, accessibility

On my website I am creating a dialog. When this dialog is visible I want to create a focus trap so the user is tabbing inside this dialog until the dialog is closed. I am able to set the tabindex of all items on my page to -1 so they can't be focussed.

But I have one problem. I have an iframe with a webform inside it. The field and submit button inside this iframe are still focusable after I've run my tabindex script. I know this is how it should work (I shouldn't be able to change iframes content) but how can I make sure these items are not focusable when the dialog is visible?

For now I just hide the form (`display:none`) when the dialog is visible and this is an okay option. But I have the feeling there is a better way and since I'm learning about accessibility I'm curious about what solutions there are for this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Generally in situations like this I just make a div that takes up the entire page and put it in between the modal and the rest of the page. That way nothing can be clicked (because they're just clicking the div) and if you want you can have a cool semi-transparent background.

Comment: @Jesse That helps with clicks, but not at all with keyboard focus, as is demanded here.

Comment: [Bootstrap’s focus trap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/js/src/util/focustrap.js) does not change `tabindex` but interrupts the tab key to set focus itself, it seems.

Comment: Thanks I will have a look at the Bootstrap code or will use it on my site.